# Django: View method that outputs large context data into an html dashboard template

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm a beginner in Django3 and just wrote an overview function to pass on some data to the template in a context variable.

I am definitely passing a lot more than I should as I only need only a few fields from each of these variables. Also, it might not be the most Django-esque way of doing things as it isn't using GenericViews or any of the more advanced Django features.

please review, comment, and provide suggestions or modifications:

```
def overview_page(request):
    user = request.user
    org = Organization.objects.filter(user=user)
    projects = Project.objects.filter(organization=org[0])
    # get first is_active project, as this is only allowed once per
    #    Organization. The model will need to be fixed post MVP for better 
    #    design 
    active_project = Project.objects.filter(organization=org[0],
                                            is_active=True)[0]
    assets = Asset.objects.filter(project=active_project)
    functional_classes = FuncClass.objects.filter(project=active_project)
    conditions = Condition.objects.filter(project=active_project)
    det_curves = DetCurve.objects.filter(project=active_project)
    func_classes = FuncClass.objects.filter(project=active_project)
    model_settings = ModelSettings.objects.filter(project=active_project)
    scenarios = Scenario.objects.filter(project=active_project)
    surface_types = SurfaceType.objects.filter(project=active_project)
    treatments = Treatment.objects.filter(project=active_project)

    context = {'user': user,
               'my_org': org[0],
               'func_class': functional_classes,
               'projects': projects,
               'active_project': active_project,
               'assets': assets,
               'conditions': conditions,
               'det_curves': det_curves,
               'func_classes': func_classes,
               'model_settings': model_settings,
               'scenarios': scenarios,
               'surface_types': surface_types,
               'treatments': treatments,
               }

    return render(request, 'asset_manager/overview.html', context)
```